# GLSL fragment shader flat in are considered dynamically uniform expressions?

Tags: opengl, glsl

In [this OpenGL forum post](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/200208-Cascade-Shadow-Mapping-artefacts-via-sampler2D-array?styleid=12) it was said that:

> In GLSL 4.x, arrays of samplers may only be indexed with dynamically-uniform expressions (in a vertex shader the expression may only involve uniform variables, in a fragment shader it may only involve uniform variables and flat-qualified inputs).

I was trying to look for this in the GLSL specification but can't find it. I'm a bit nervous to try and spend time changing up code if it doesn't work. My biggest worry is if I do it and it somehow appears to work on my computer but I'm invoking undefined behavior without knowing (which would probably end badly somewhere, sometime).

An example of what I'd like to do (I have not run this, it's an example and should be considered pseudocode):

```
// Fragment shader

in vec3 uv;
flat in uint index;  // Assume in the range of 0 to 3 inclusive

uniform sampler3D textureSampler[4];

void main() {
    someColor = texture(textureSampler[index], uv);
    // ...
}
```

Is this defined behavior because it has the **flat** qualifier? Or no?

Comment: It is definitely not possible in 3.3 since according to the [OpenGL Wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Opaque_arrays), in version before 4.0 opaque arrays could only be accessed by a compile-time integral Constant Expressions. Unfortunately, I couldn't find out if a attribute with flat modifier is considered dynamically uniform in > 4.0

Comment: @BDL thank you for looking, also that 3.3 information is useful for me so that's good!

Comment: @Water: "*Further, this page seems to imply flat works as well...*" It most certainly does not. Where do you see anything that suggests any such thing?

Comment: @NicolBolas I was wrong, link removed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very complex issue, one that has actually had its specification language change (thanks to Vulkan actually clarifying a lot of these issues, language wording which was copied back into OpenGL). Indeed, there are a couple of outstanding issues on this subject in the OpenGL bug database.

But in short, no: `flat`-qualified variables are not dynamically uniform. Or more specifically, they are not *generally* dynamically uniform.

The thing to remember about a dynamically uniform expression is that it's about whether the *value* of the expression is different for different invocations within the "invocation group" (explained below). If the value is the same for all invocations, then it is dynamically uniform.

An "invocation group" is defined in GLSL 4.60 as:

> An invocation group is the complete set of invocations collectively processing a particular compute workgroup or graphical operation, where the scope of a "graphical operation" is implementation dependent, but at least as large as a single triangle or patch, and at most as large as a single rendering
>   command, as defined by the client API.

Unfortunately, this "the client API" language was copied verbatim from the SPIR-V specification. The client API in this case is OpenGL, but the OpenGL specification doesn't actually define how big an invocation group is.

The [current OpenGL issue tracking this omission](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenGL-API/issues/15) tells us that the ARB's intent is that the OpenGL definition more or less matches the Vulkan definition. And the Vulkan definition is:

> For graphics shaders, an invocation group is an implementation-dependent subset of the set of shader invocations of a given shader stage which are produced by a single drawing command.

So an invocation group is bigger than a single primitive. Therefore, a `flat`-qualified variable will only be dynamically uniform if you just so happen to pass the same value to every primitive in the drawing command.

So you cannot assume that a `flat` qualified variable is dynamically uniform just because it is `flat` qualified. You could assume that for `uniform` or `const` qualified globals, or from similar data. But unless you've done something that ensures that each invocation within the rendering command gets the same `flat` value, you cannot use it in a place where dynamically uniform expressions are needed.